# How to specify id options in 'doctrine:generate:entity' command?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using `doctrine:generate:entity` command to generate entities. I want to use `guid` (`string(32)`) instead of `integer` as id type, but when I specify it like `id:string(32)` in `--fields` option I get following error:

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]
Duplicate definition of column 'id' on entity 'Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Test' in a field or discriminator column mapping.
```

What should I do to get it working?

**@answer:**
As @loicfavory wrote in comment to his answer the only way is to extend `Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\Generator\DoctrineEntityGenerator` class where `id` options are set manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Id is automatically generated by the DoctrineEntityGenerator with the integer type.
I think that if you specify it with the --fields option, it duplicate the creation of the field.

That's the error you got.

Did you try to change the type manually in the entity class, after the command create it ?

Comment: Yes, I know that id is automatically generated, I'm searching for a way to redeclare it. Sure, I can change id type in entity class, but I really want to avoid it...

Comment: I don't think you can change it, the field is set manualy in Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\Generator\DoctrineEntityGenerator. Maybe you should develop you're own generator. I did it for the CRUD generator, by extending the classes I needed.

Comment: Yes, I've found it a minute ago... It seems the only way is what you've suggested. Thanks for your help.